# Molecular MC simulation is not equilibrating

Tags: c#, simulation, physics

Suppose, a polymer has *N* monomers in its chain. I want to simulate its movement using the **bead-spring** model. However, there was no periodic boundary condition applied. Coz, points were generated such that they never cross the boundary.

So, I wrote the following program.

- [Polymer chain simulation with Monte Carlo method](https://github.com/mns-csharp/PolymerMotionSimulation)

I am using 1 million steps. The energy is not fluctuating as expected. After several thousand steps the curve goes totally flat.

[image]

[image]

The X-axis is steps. Y-axis is total energy.

Can anyone check the source code and tell me what I should change?

N.B. I am especially concerned with the function that calculates the total energy of the polymer.

Probably, the algorithm is incorrect.

```
    public double GetTotalPotential()
    {
        double totalBeadPotential = 0.0;
        double totalSpringPotential = 0.0;

        // calculate total bead-energy
        for (int i = 0; i < beadsList.Count; i++)
        {
            Bead item_i = beadsList[i];
            Bead item_i_plus_1 = null;

            try
            {
                item_i_plus_1 = beadsList[i + 1];

                if (i != beadsList.Count - 1)
                {
                    // calculate total spring energy.
                    totalSpringPotential += item_i.GetHarmonicPotential(item_i_plus_1);
                }
            }
            catch { }

            for (int j = 0; j < beadsList.Count; j++)
            {
                if (i != j)
                {
                    Bead item_j = beadsList[j];
                    totalBeadPotential += item_i.GetPairPotential(item_j);
                    //Console.Write(totalBeadPotential + "\n");
                    //Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            }
        }

        return totalBeadPotential + totalSpringPotential;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem of this application is that simulations (`Simulation.SimulateMotion`) are run in separate thread in parallel to the draw timer (`SimulationGuiForm.timer1_Tick`) and share the same state (`polymerChain`) without any sync/signaling, so some mutations of `polymerChain` are skipped completely (not drawn) and when the simulation is finished (far before the finish of the drawing)  the `timer1_Tick` will redraw the same `polymerChain`. You can easily check that by adding counter to `Simulation` and increasing it in the `SimulateMotion`:

```
public class Simulation
{
    public static int Simulations = 0; // counter
    public static void SimulateMotion(PolymerChain polymerChain, int iterations)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            Simulations++; // bump the counter
            // rest of the code
            // ...
```

And checking it in `timer1_Tick`:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    // previous code
    if (Simulation.Simulations == totalIterations)
    {
        // breakpoint or Console.Writeline() ...
        // will be hit as soon as "the curve goes totally flat" 
    }

    DrawZGraph();            
}
```

You need to rewrite your application in such way that `SimulateMotion` either stores iterations in some collection which is consumed by `timer1_Tick` (basically implementing producer-consumer pattern, for example you can try using [`BlockingCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-6.0), like I do in the [pull request](https://github.com/mns-csharp/PolymerMotionSimulation/pull/1)) or performs it's actions only when the current state is rendered.

Comment: @user366312 I'm sorry to say but this is definitely the reason for the behaviour. Here is [proof](https://github.com/mns-csharp/PolymerMotionSimulation/pull/1), or in [my repo](https://github.com/gurustron/PolymerMotionSimulation).

Comment: @user366312 Also I don't know how some completely different code can be proof of what is or is not an issue with discussed one. There are at least next differences which I quickly found - the simulation thread is started on the button click (not with start of the program as in the discussed code), timer interval is not set. In the discussed app if you wait long enough and press "start" you will see flat line from the get go.

Comment: I am unable to run the source code. I am using VS2015 and .net framework 4.6.2. The argument of `TryTake` is showing a compile-time error `The name currPolymerChain doesn't exist in the current context`.

Comment: @user366312 I don't have such old VS version on my machine. I've tried to fix the code so the older compiler is supported (see the [new pr](https://github.com/mns-csharp/PolymerMotionSimulation/pull/2)). But in general I suggest to upgrade to the newer compiler/VS versions so new C# versions goodies are supported (unless you have compatibility requirements)